# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Google Font

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts

I'm trying to use a google font on my rails app, but I'm getting this message on my console and the font is not loaded.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://pre.blabloo.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I got the same error on my localhost:3000. I add the following code to my application helper but I still getting the error.

```
after_filter :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers 
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'  
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*' 
end
```

or

```
after_filter :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers 
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://pre.blabloo.com'  
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*' 
end
```

But nothing happens

Any help please.

UPDATE

---

I also tried the rack-cors gem like this:

On my config/application:

```
config.middleware.insert_before "ActionDispatch::Static", "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins 'http://localhost:3000'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

But it does not work. Now I have another cross domaing problem with youtube.

Comment: What does your link tag look like where you are including the google font?

Comment: are you using nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't solve the problem with any configuration of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', so I decide to upload the font to the server.

Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would add it like this to your application.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => %w{GET POST OPTIONS}.join(",") # or whatever else you would like to allow
}
```

works for me.

Comment: Into config/application.rb

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your problem and it was working for me with the following layout and `stylesheet_link_tag`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SoAccessControl</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I've set the right `font-family` in my stylesheet and it worked. After that, I tried to set the headers. And that worked to:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  after_filter :set_cors

  def set_cors
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://example.com'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
  end
end
```

Here the verification:
[image: verify]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robin. I tried your solution, but I still getting the following error on my console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access." If I upload this to my pre or production server, I get the same error but address change to pre.blabloo.com or www.blabloo.com. Do you have another idea. Thanks

Comment: No, because I can't replicate your problem.